# react сортировка объектов при изменении инпута

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть данные типа

```js
{
    id: 1,
    title: 'most popular language in 2019',
    description:
        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing…res mollitia optio aperiam sit delectus deleniti.',
    author: 'John',
}
```

Как сделать сортировку по названию с помощью инпута?

Они рендерятся в

```js
render() {
  const {articles} = this.props;
  return(
    <div>
      <input type="text" onChange={this.onChangeHandler.bind(this)}/>
      <ul>
          {
            articles.map((article)=>{
              return (
                <li key={article.id}>
                  <ArticleListItem article={article}/>
                </li>
              )
            })
          }
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

onChangeHandler(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    console.log(this.state.articles)
    // var newArray = this.state.articles.title.filter((d)=>{
    //   return d.indexOf(e.target.value) !== -1 
    // });
    // console.log(newArray)
    // this.setState({
    //   users:newArray
    // })
}
```

Comment: Под сортировкой имеется в виду фильтрация?

Answer (score 0):

```
onChangeHandler(e) {
  const { value } = e.target;

  this.setState(state => ({
    articles: state. articles.filter(article =>
      article.title.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()),
    ));
  }));
}
```